# How many $n\times(n-1)$ $ 01$ matrices are there?(Each row is different. There is only one column with one 0 or one 1)

Tags: combinatorics, programming

There is an $n\times(n-1)$ matrix, the elements of it are $0$ or $1$. Each row is different. There is only one column with one $0$ or one $1$. How many such matrices are there?
I got this question from Game WOW, Maze patterns in the fog of the woods of Seth. Players must find
one "special" image from four images.

For example, we choose picture **3** because it is empty while others are solid. [image]

For another example, we choose picture **4** because it is a leaf while others are flowers.
[image]

I code for a program and get there are $24$ combinations of pictures suit the rule. And I have put the sequences into OEIS but I can't find the answer. Is there a formula that can calculate how many images there are when there are $n$ images?

Sorry for  my poor English. I will edit my words if I break the rule of MSE.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos  ok,sir,I will edit it

Comment: How do you get "$24$ combinations of pictures"? What were the sequences that you put into OEIS?

Comment: @Gerry Myerson sir,I code for a program,to Enumerate the 4-bit combinations of 0-7, then convert the numbers of 0-7 to binary, and then judge whether the conditions are met

Comment: @Gerry Myerson https://www.dooccn.com/cpp/#id/0df5720416b72dfe012929e8c60f7da6